# Form CSS - magin

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to put a bit of space between a question and entry in a form. Here's the code. I tried

```
.signup entry {
 margin-top: 30 px;  
}
```

which I thought should work, but that didn't work.

I also tried assigning a class to questions

so,

```
=label_tag(:email,"Email: ", class: "example")
```

and then

```
.example {
   margin-bottom: 30px;  
}
```

thought this should work, but still didn't.

What am I doing wrong...? Thanks so much for your help

```
.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3{:style=>"text-align:full; background: rgba(33, 181, 250,.68); padding-top:0px; padding-bottom: 5px; margin-bottom:10px; color: white; margin-top: 30px;"}
  %br
  = form_tag('/borrower_response', method:"post", class:"borrower-form") do 
    .row
      .col-md-6
        =label_tag(:name,"Name:",)
        =text_field_tag(:name, nil, class: "signup-entry")
      .col-md-6
        =label_tag(:email,"Email: ",)
        =text_field_tag(:email, nil, class: "signup-entry") 

    .row     
      .col-md-6
        =label_tag(:amount,"How much are you looking to refinance or borrow?") 
        =text_field_tag(:amount, nil, class: "signup-entry")
      .col-md-6
        =label_tag(:current_rate, "What rate do you pay now, if applicable?")
        =text_field_tag(:current_rate, nil, class: "signup-entry")

    %br
```

**UPDATE:**

OK just tried putting %br right before the second .row and this did the trick. With that, I can't control exactly how much space I create tho - if anyone knows how I could use margin-bottom/margin-top properties, etc. to do just that, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: What is that syntax anyway?

Comment: `text-align:full;` !?

Comment: This is not `HTML` proper syntax. Please add the correct tag for your Client-side language. **EDIT** Found out it was a [Ruby-on-Rails](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/label_tag) syntax. Please add the proper tag depending on the version of RoR you are using to get proper answers.

Comment: Sorry really new to this - what do you mean by adding the proper tag depending on the version of RoR..?

Answer (score 0):

You are using space between values and units: `margin-top: 30 px;` should be `margin-top: 30px;`.

What is: `text-align:full;`, should be: `left`, `right` or `justify`

Comment: Hmm not using space didn't work... do you still think text-align is the problem?

Comment: There is no such property as `text-align: full;`

Comment: fixed text-align but didn't make any noticeable difference.